# golang mqtt publish and subscribe

Tags: go, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

Does anybody know where I can get some example MQTT client Go (golang) code that does both publish and subscribe in an infinite loop ?

I am messaging with a Mosquitto broker running on MacOs.

In more detail...

1. Get a message from the network (a topic)
2. Compute something based on that message
3. Send the result of the computation back to the network (topic)

Here is the code I am using:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
 MQTT "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
"os"
"time"
)

var knt int

var f MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) 
{ 
   fmt.Printf("MSG: %s\n", msg.Payload())
   text:= fmt.Sprintf("this is result msg #%d!", knt)
   knt++
   token := client.Publish("nn/result", 0, false, text)
   token.Wait()
}

func main() {
   knt = 0

   opts := MQTT.NewClientOptions().AddBroker("tcp://localhost:1883")
   opts.SetClientID("mac-go")
   opts.SetDefaultPublishHandler(f)

   c := MQTT.NewClient(opts)
   if token := c.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        panic(token.Error())
   }

  if token := c.Subscribe("nn/sensors", 0, nil); token.Wait() && 
     token.Error() != nil {
     fmt.Println(token.Error())
     os.Exit(1)
  }

  time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
} //end of main
```

I looked through the GoDocs for some hint as to how to keep the connections open but nothing seems pertinent. I can certainly do an infinite loop 
over the 'subscribe' but that seems inefficient.

Comment: Asking for tutorials it's off topic for Stack Overflow, show us what you've already tried and somebody will help you fix it

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the feedback. I found a solution... I think. I added the solution code to the question. It runs in a test environment. Now I have to try it in a real environment.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I looked through the GoDocs for some hint as to how to keep the connections open but nothing seems pertinent. I can certainly do an infinite loop over the 'subscribe' but that seems inefficient.

Ok. Found a solution at . https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/master/cmd/stdoutsub/main.go.
Essentially, I had to open up a channel for the subscribe.
Here is the new code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    MQTT "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

var knt int
var f MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {
    fmt.Printf("MSG: %s\n", msg.Payload())
    text := fmt.Sprintf("this is result msg #%d!", knt)
    knt++
    token := client.Publish("nn/result", 0, false, text)
    token.Wait()
}

func main() {
    knt = 0
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    opts := MQTT.NewClientOptions().AddBroker("tcp://localhost:1883")
    opts.SetClientID("mac-go")
    opts.SetDefaultPublishHandler(f)
    topic := "nn/sensors"

    opts.OnConnect = func(c MQTT.Client) {
            if token := c.Subscribe(topic, 0, f); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
                    panic(token.Error())
            }
    }
    client := MQTT.NewClient(opts)
    if token := client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
            panic(token.Error())
    } else {
            fmt.Printf("Connected to server\n")
    }
    <-c
}
```

Comment: I edited my question and moved my answer into the answer section.

Comment: > MQTT "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang" 
What is the rationale for the override? If there is one, why not this:
> FMT "fmt"